# How to custom UINavigationBar's animation in transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, transition

In wwdc 2013, it says that navigation bar will only be crossfade in any custom navigationcontroller transtion.

But , I also found some apps 's navigation bar will contain some other animation in transition . (eg.in the video i post , the navigation bar's title will moved) .And it'clear that it is using the custom transition because the left barbuttonitem's title will not move. how to do this kind of animation of navigation bar

video link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOpI5K6ejtU

Comment: That's default animation...not sure what you wanted to have

Comment: @Tj3n , that's not the default animation . you can open the setting app to see the default pop animation of system . the left barbuttonitem 's animation is totally different from this